# Sickly white true Earthlings superseded by modern man short story

Tags: story-identification

I read this in an anthology way back in (I think) the 1960s, I don't recall many of the finer details.

Two men are chatting on a boat and one has just returned from a jungle expedition, possibly the Amazon. He narrates the yarn.

He'd tracked down rumours of a Lost tribe to a small area but his native guides had a taboo and wouldn't accompany him for the final part of his journey.

He finds remnants of a millions of years old spacecraft from Mars (I don't remember how he determined it was Martian in origin) but while examining it he came under attack by these primitive looking sickly white humanoids and has to flee back to civilisation, he described them as quite small and feeble looking (possibly he said they were boneless)

The other guy says that he's surprised the Martians have survived so long as they clearly can't compete with Earthmen.

The explorer replies something like "Oh no, they're not the Martian descendants, we are, they're what's left of the true Earthmen"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Without_Bones

Sort of a silly story in a way, not sure why you would call the indigenous "men" men but that is for sure the story you are looking for.

Kersh wrote a lot of stuff, hard to describe his subgenre of science fiction but it seems many of his stories are of the same "flavor" as MWB.